# How to make svg text and absolutely positioned html text identical?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have absolutely position div with top/left set to 10, 10 and I have absolutely positioned svg element at 0, 0 with text element at 10, 10. How do I style both so they look completely identical? (ie it should look like single text line visually) I have applied `dominant-baseline: hanging` for svg text which properly positions it exactly where I want but there is some small margin for html text at the top. Is it possible to remove it? I am able to achieve desired behaviour by setting `line-height: 0.8` but I want to find proper solution.

```css
.html-text {
   color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   left: 10px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 36px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   line-height: 1;
}

svg {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 36px;
   transform-origin: 0 0;
   dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <svg>
    <text x="10" y="10">Hello world!</text>
    <rect x="10px" y="10px" width="220px" height="40px" fill="green" opacity="0.1"/>
 </svg>
 <div class="html-text">Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution I found that uses `line-height` and keeps the `top` and `left` properties the same over the classes: https://jsfiddle.net/yobwhv16/44/

The only changing value is in the `tspan dy` positions where you have to offset the first line by `2px` then every one after that by the value you have for `line-height`

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <svg>
  <text>
 <tspan x="0" dy="2px">Hello world!</tspan>
 <tspan x="0" dy="32px">Hello world Again!</tspan>
 <tspan x="0" dy="32px">Hello world How are you today?</tspan> 
</text>
<!--<rect width="500px" height="40px" fill="green" opacity="0.1"/>-->
 </svg>
  <div class="html-text">Hello world!<br>Hello world Again!<br>Hello world How are you today?</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.html-text {
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;

  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;

  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 32px;

  font-size: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

svg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;

 height: 150px;
 width: 600px;

 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 36px;
 vertical-align: middle;

 transform-origin: 0 0;
 dominant-baseline: hanging;
}
```

Comment: Like I did with line-height you also hardcoded line-height to 32 and dy specified in pixels(any explanation for the 2px for the first line?). I need general solution which would work with any font/font size combination without relying on hard-coded values.

Comment: Totally understandable, I will take another look for you!
Also currently no explanation for the 2px in the first line other then getting it positioned correctly